# How can you limit cpu usage in R?

Tags: r, cpu, mxnet

When I run an R script to generate a model through machine learning frameworks like `mxnet` and `tensorflow`, I see in task manager that the cpu usage reaches 100%.
I have 2x 2.7 ghz and the pc becomes too slow until it blocks.

Is there a method to limit cpu usage in R with a slower model training time?

Comment: maybe set the number of threads to 1?

Comment: i haven't set a number of threads, the default parameter is 1

Comment: so when you restart Windows, and immediately run the script, you see only 1 processor being blogged down in the Task Mgr?

Comment: where do i can see this processors in task manager?

Answer (score 0):

MXnet looks at some environment variables:
https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/faq/env_var.html

You could experiment by setting MXNET_GPU_WORKER_NTHREADS=2 at the command line, for example.

Note that you may have to restart R after you set the environment variables for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

0) As mentioned above, you could manipulate the environment variables that dictate how many workers you want.

1) You could adjust your workbook context to use only one of the CPUs.

> e.g. z = nd.ones(shape=(3,3), ctx=mx.cpu(0))

2) Could resort to using OS-level tools, in Windows there are a few: https://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process

Vishaal